# Nginx, django, docker, refuses connection over localhost

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, nginx

I'd like to find out what is haunting my dockerized Django, Postgres, Gunicorn, Nginx project.

```
`/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found`
nginx         | 2021/10/27 15:40:34 [error] 22#22: *2 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.29.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "0.0.0.0:8000"
nginx         | 172.29.0.1 - - [27/Oct/2021:15:40:34 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36" "-
```

I cannot understand why it complains about the index.html when I essentially only redirect traffic from Django on port 8000 and have replaced the config file for nginx.

In `nginx.conf` I have tried to change     `listen 80;` to     `listen 8000;`
and tried to change and then to delete the entry `server_name localhost;`

In docker-compose I have tried to change ports, such as

```
   ports:
      - 8000:80
```

-->

```
   ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

I have inspected the container and default `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` is deleted and replaced by the new `nginx.conf`

It's probably something very simple, but I cannot see it.

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                   NAMES
ea9da69663eb   nn_nginx         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp, :::8000->80/tcp   nginx
fcc396bd0e56   nn_django_app    "/usr/src/app/entryp…"   7 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   8000/tcp                                django_app
2653621d29ff   postgres:14.0-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   5432/tcp                                db1
```

or with changed ports

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                               NAMES
e15109bacc66   nn_nginx         "/docker-entrypoint.…"   28 minutes ago   Up 28 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   nginx
7ee41d873e3d   nn_django_app    "/usr/src/app/entryp…"   29 minutes ago   Up 28 minutes   8000/tcp                                            django_app
e9f14bd6e6b8   postgres:14.0-alpine   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   29 minutes ago   Up 28 minutes   5432/tcp
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  # Database containers
  db1:
    container_name: db1
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - db1_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./postgres/.env
    networks:
     - db1_network

  # Web container
  django_app:
    container_name: django_app
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - django_static_volume:/usr/src/app/static
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    networks:
     - db1_network
     - nginx_network
    expose:
      - 8000 
    depends_on:
      - db1
    command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application -w 3 -b :8000

  # Reverse proxy container (nginx)
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - django_static_volume:/usr/src/app/django_files/static
    networks:
      - nginx_network
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    depends_on:
      - django_app


networks:
  db1_network:
    driver: bridge
  nginx_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  db1_volume:
  django_static_volume:
```

**Nginx DOCKERFILE**

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream django_backend {
    server django_app:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass http://django_backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://django_backend;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static/admin/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/django_files/static/admin/;
    }

    location /static/rest_framework/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/django_files/static/rest_framework/;
    }
}
```

selected from django settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites', 

    # Third-party
    'corsheaders',

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SECRET_KEY = 'secretsecretsecret'
DEBUG = False
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0', 'localhost']


ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static'))] 
STATIC_ROOT = str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('staticfiles')) 
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [ 
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

For the port `8000:80` in your `docker-compose` the `8000` is the port that the browser will try to connect, `80` is the port that the docker container port. That means that you need to set the same port `80` for the `nginx config`.

In the Nginx config, you only set the location for `/api` and `/admin` and `staticfiles`. I only see you try to `GET /` Did you try to `GET` your `api` and `admin` instead ?

Comment: you are a *, thanks!, I completely forgot to add location /, couldn't see it until you pointed it out.